# A "math font error" I fixed but, don't know what was wrong

Tags: fonts, errors, slanted

I was typing my homework and got this error:

`! LaTeX Error: \mathfrak allowed only in math mode.`

Recently I added some macros to my macro file that gives mathfrak text when used so, I figured I must have used that command without using math mode. I looked around and saw that since I last compiled I had not used that command, so I start commenting out stuff till my document would compile. Anyway long story short it looked like when my document got over a page it would output the error and not compile. I confirmed this by opening a new document (a template I use) that loads my macros file and typed a bit, then made a new page then typed a bit, no math at all, and it would output the same error.

I guess the culprit was this command:
`\renewcommand{\sl}{\mathfrak{sl}}`. I changed it to `\newcommand{\sla}{\mathfrak{sl}}` and now I can get over a page without an error.

I would like to know why it would only output an error after a page. Also it would be cool to know how I could get the `\sl` command I defined without that undesirable behavior.

Edit: Here is an example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sl}{\mathfrak{sl}}
\begin{document}
P
\end{document}
```

For some reason this example doesn't need a second page. Also it looks like the error has something to do with `fancy`.

Comment: `\sl` gives slanted text and it is already defined. You may use `\newcommand{\Sl}{\mathfrak{sl}}` instead.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The command `\sl`, while OK in Plain-TeX documents, is considered deprecated for LaTeX documents; use either `\textsl{…}` or `{\slshape …}` instead of `\sl`. However, since you're not actually looking to use slanted glyphs, it's best to stay away from this command; in particular, do not try to redefine the command `\sl`, as doing so may break other things in your document. Instead, use a name for your macro; `\sla` will work, though I'd like to encourage you to find a more mnemonic name that's not already been taken.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with the fact you changed `\sl` to `\sla`. In the first case you were using `\sl` outside math mode. This is the error you got. And anyway, as said in other comments, don't redefine `\sl`

Comment: @karlkoeller I didn't use `\sl` outside of math mode. I mentioned that the problem only occured when my document got to the second page, even in documents with no math.

Comment: @Mico So it is likely there error occurs do to some conflict that is implicitly used? `sla` is an acronym, but maybe I will change it to something a bit more mnemonic.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please try to give the minimal working example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)) in which your problem occurs. Creating it is the first step in debugging and helps us tremendously in pin-pointing where the issue may lie. In particular it should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @PaulPlummer - Because `\sl` is a fairly low level (as well as well-established, though deprecated) command, it may still be in use in various LaTeX packages, whether loaded explicitly by you or by other packages that are in use. Redefining the `\sl` macro may therefore cause unexpected and unforeseeable problems. It sure looks like you've encountered one such problem, and more might be lurking. That's why I recommend you *not* redefine the `\sl` command at all and, rather, come up with an entirely new name for your shortcut macro.

Comment: @Mico: I agree, that is the problem, could you please put that into an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for posting an MWE that generates the problem behavior you're looking to fix.

The problem -- i.e., the error message about `\mathfrak` being used outside of math mode -- seems to arise because you're also loading the `fancyhdr` package: Comment out the instructions `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` and `\pagestyle{fancy}`, and no more error message is produced.

Sure enough, inside the file `fancyhdr.sty`, one finds the following instructions:

```
\if@twoside
  \fancyhead[el,or]{\fancyplain{}{\sl\rightmark}}
  \fancyhead[er,ol]{\fancyplain{}{\sl\leftmark}}
\else
  \fancyhead[l]{\fancyplain{}{\sl\rightmark}}
  \fancyhead[r]{\fancyplain{}{\sl\leftmark}}
\fi
```

Given that `\sl` really shouldn't be used in LaTeX documents anymore, the best solution would be for the package to be amended to use `\slshape` instead of `\sl` in the code shown above. The next best solution -- and the one that's available immediately -- is for the user (you!) not to try to redefine `\sl` in the first place.

---

**Update March 2020**: At some point since I originally wrote this answer, the `fancyhdr` package *was* updated to use `\slshape` rather than `\sl` in all four instances shown in the code chunk above. The following paragraphs are thus mainly (hopefully...) of general interest; however, they no longer describe the current properties of the `fancyhdr` package.

*What* is it about the command `\sl` -- and the related font-changing commands `\rm`, `\sf`, `\tt`, `\bf`, `\it`, and `\sc` -- that makes them "deprecated" for use in LaTeX? For one, these commands are no longer defined in the LaTeX "kernel" (i.e., you won't find them in the file `latex.ltx` in your TeX distribution) but only in "class" files, e.g., in `article.cls`. Second, to the extent the command `\sl` is defined at all, it's generally set up as follows:

```
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sl}{\normalfont\slshape}{\@nomath\sl}
```

(The macros `\normalfont` and `\slshape`, naturally, *are* defined in the LaTeX kernel.)

This definition of `\sl`, which  invokes `\normalfont` *before* `\slshape`, is deliberately crafted to mimic the action of the original Plain-TeX `\sl` macro. Because of the presence of the `\normalfont` instruction -- which executes the four instructions `\encodingdefault`, `\familydefault`, `\seriesdefault`, and `\shapedefault` -- one cannot "combine" several old-style font declaration commands. Thus, an instruction such as `\bf\it` will *not* create ***bold-italic*** output; it will only create *italic* output. (Similarly, `\it\bf` will only create **bold** output.)

One of the (many) advantages of using `\bfseries\itshape` instead of `\bf\it` is precisely that it lets you "combine" the two font-changing commands. (Of course, if the font family in use doesn't provide bold-italic glyphs, TeX/LaTeX can't employ them. However, the *availability* of specific combinations of font weights and shapes is an entirely separate issue.)

Comment: The code in `fancyhdr.sty` should be changed. Another possibility could be to define the header in the document, but the possibility that another non updated package calls `\sl` would still be there. `:-(`

Comment: @egreg - I agree with you that the code in the `fancyhdr` should be changed. But, as you say, there are lots and lots of LaTeX packages out there that still use the deprecated font-changing commands. I suspect that tracking down all deprecated commands used in files stored on the CTAN, contacting the packages' maintainers, and asking them to update the deprecated code is a task that even Hercules would take a rather long time to achieve. (No diversion of rivers allowed -- or possible...)